# Customizing a BigCommerce product listing

Tags: bigcommerce

This is a section of code for listing the name of a product in list-item.html:

```
<h4 class="listItem-title">
    <a href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
</h4>
```

Below the name, I would like to add "Date Added: " and the date it was added to the website, but only if the item is in the "What's New" category. I can't figure out the syntax for saying "If this product is in the What's New category, then display "Date Added: " and date it was added.

Does anyone have a clue where I would start to do this? I am still very new to BigCommerce.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{{date_added}}` to display the date that the product was added, but adding logic to display it in a specific category is a little more complex.

In list-item.html, {{category}} is scoped to the individual product being rendered, so doing something like the example below will only work if the item appears *only* in the What's New Category.

```
{{#if category '===' 'What's New'}}
    {{date_added}}
{{/if}}
```

Another option would be to create a custom template for the category page. That would give you the control to create a custom list-item.html component that references {{date_added}} just on a certain category page. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwrVN5QrEZY&t=232s) is a good starting point for creating custom templates, and you can find documentation [here](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/template-files/custom-templates/authoring-testing-uploading-custom-templates).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have the date added showing up now, on every item. Most items are in multiple categories, so I decided to take the custom template that you suggested.

Comment: I copied the item-list contents and pasted them into a new file names item-list-whats-new.html. I created the custom directory under template/pages and placed the new file into it. Next I modified the .stencil file like this: 
 "customLayouts": {
    "brand": {},
    "category": {
      "list-item-whats-new.html": ["/new-hand-guns/", "/whats-new/", "/new-long-guns/", "/new-other-items"]
    },
    "page": {},
    "product": {}
  }

Comment: I guess I don't know how to use this system very well. When I hit Enter to get a new line, it posts instead. Anyway, when i try to view the whats new page now, all I get is a broken image symbol, and a piece of text that says Date Added:. That's it. I must be doing something wrong. Or left out a step?

Comment: You'll want to make sure that you're starting with category.html as your parent for the custom template. Category.html requires a series of nested components (you can follow the tree down from here https://github.com/bigcommerce/cornerstone/blob/master/templates/pages/category.html#L45 to listing-item.html). It'll be similar to the video I sent you where the product page pulls in a custom component--your parent category page will require a component that requires a component...and on until you get to a custom version of list-item.html that includes `{{date_added}}`. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Got IT. Thanks so much. Once I figured out the file to put in my Custom/Category page was the one under Pages/Product Listing, I was able to follow the logic and create the new files needed for the custom page. The video was kind of vague as to which directory to use for which files. Thanks again!!!

Comment: One more question? Is there a way to format the date_added to show DayOfTheWeek, Date 3LetterMonth, 4DigitYear?

Comment: Glad you were able to get it working! I'd probably reach for something like moment.js to help with the date formatting: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: I will look into that. Thank you very much.